# Can a remote server send response to a local client on a custom port?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, networking

For network gurus out there, I'll like to ask some questions regarding some unique setup where the server will be sending a request to a client on `localhost` on a certain port.

I have a cloudy understanding of some network fundamentals that I hope you'll be able to help me out.

Kindly check the image below:
[image]

Basically, there's a static website hosted in AWS s3 and at some point this website will send a request to `https://localhost:8001`.

I was expecting that it will connect to the nginx container listening on port 8001 in my local machine, but it results in 504 gateway error.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible for a remote server to directly send data to a client at a particular port by addressing it as `localhost`?
2. How is it possible for the static website to communicate to my local docker container?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"Is it possible for a remote server to directly send data to a client at a particular port by addressing it as localhost?"* - no, because the localhost of the remote server **is** the remote server. However you do not have a remote server at all here, you only have a static website in S3 which is downloaded and displayed by the client, all javascript "logic" etc. is run in the client browser. And that javascript logic can simply talk to localhost because now you are "on" your own local machine.

Comment: The javascript talking to localhost works basically the same way as you entering the url of localhost in your browser and hitting enter. The request never leaves your machine, never traverses the internet, etc. If the request does not hit your actual container or nginx then something with your configuration is off, entirely unrelated to AWS.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. If i understood it correctly, since it's entire SPA website run by javascript, the `localhost` refers to the localhost of the client.

One detail that i forgot was there was a cloudfront distribution set up and has an origin that points to the s3 bucket.
Will that play a role here?

Comment: No, that is irrelevant. That only is responsible for the initial delivery of the static website, not for how that website behaves in the client.

Comment: Your diagram mentions port 8001, but your example mentions port 8081.  Are you confusing ports in your setup?  Also, if you're using https for your local webserver, have you gone through the work of creating a self-signed cert and installing it in the browser?

Comment: Oh, about the port that was a mistake on my part. Thanks for pointing that out. I'll edit the question.

With regards to the self-signed certificate, I did installed it inside the nginx docker container itself using mkcert, but not on the host machine.
Will aws refuse to process the request if that's the case?

Answer (score 0):

In the setup you show, in the context of a Web site, `localhost` isn't in your picture at all.  It's the desktop machine running the end user's Web browser.

More generally, you show several boxes in your diagram – "local machine", "Docker VM", "individual container", "server in Amazon's data center" – and within each of these boxes, if they make an outbound request to `localhost`, it reaches back to itself.

You have two basic options here:

(1) Set up a separate (Route 53) DNS name for your back-end service, and use that `https://backend.example.com/...` host name in your front-end application.

(2) Set up an HTTP reverse proxy that forwards `/`, `/assets`, ... to S3, and `/api` to the back-end service.  In your front-end application use only the HTTP path with no host name at all.

The second option is more work to set up, but once you've set it up, it's much easier to develop code for.  Webpack has a similar "proxy the backend" option for day-to-day development.  This setup means the front-end application itself doesn't care where it's running, and you don't need to rebuild the application if the URL changes (or an individual developer needs to run it on their local system).

Comment: Thanks for the anwer.

Btw, Sorry for the confusion. Regarding the diagram what I meant by the local machine  in the diagram is actually the desktop machine or the user's PC -- in other words, the local machine == localhost of the client.

Comment: In addition to that, the setup is only for day-to-day testing.
does the `localhost` still point to AWS data center where the s3 bucket is or does it refer to the localhost of the client? Based on the comment of @luk2302, I have this understanding that once the SPA website has been fetched, `localhost` points to the client's IP address.

Adding to that it is a SPA app and javascript then powers it after it has been requested.

The other question is, can I create a DNS record and point it to the `localhost`, for example: `https://backend.example.com` -> `https://localhost:8001`?

Comment: The browser is the one making the HTTP call, and `localhost` is the machine running the browser.  A DNS (A or AAAA) record just resolves a name to an IP address and does not include any information about ports.